# Does this Windows Desktop & Andoid Phone Display on one screen really exist?

Tags: windows, android

I am going to buy a new TFT, and while scrolling I saw the product image of the ***NEC Multisync EA294WMi-BK***. While I understand, that this is a product image, I would like to know if this is possible: having the windows desktop alongside the android phone screen on one monitor.
[image]

Is it possible to do this? If so, how do I go about setting it up?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, so I reworded you question a little to help avoid it being closed. If you disagree with my edits, feel free to [edit] it the way you like.

Comment: Thank you! I am happy with the edit! I posted the specifications as it might be a "hardware" feature of this special model, just to be sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this video - http://www.necdisplay.com/SupportAndServices/HTMLs/PicturebyPicture.html
You can plug in 2 display sources, and the monitor can display both at the same time side by side. This means that you could conceivably plug in an Android device and have it display on the screen at the same time as your normal PC display.

Comment: I've just recently seen similiar products by other manufacturers as well... seems to be the next big thing...